# Catchable fatal error: Object of class SimpleImage could not be converted to string (casting a var is not working)

Tags: php, mysql

I implemented following image-resizer:
http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Now I want to insert the uploaded image into a db.

```
include('simple_image.php');
$image_rez = new SimpleImage();
$image_rez->load($file);
$image_rez->resizeToWidth(990);
$image_rez->save($image_name.'.jpg');

$sql = "INSERT INTO
            `Media_images` (`ID`,`Name`,`Image`,`Size`)
        VALUES
            (?, ?, ?, ?)
        ";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

if (!$stmt) {
    echo 'Datenbankfehler\n';
    echo $db->error;
}

$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['id'], $image_name, (string)$image_rez, $image_size);

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo 'Datenbankfehler\n';
    echo $stmt->error;
}

//Cache löschen
destroy(PATH);
//Redirekt wenn erfolgreich eingetragen
header("location:../../index.php?section=media");
die;
```

But Im getting following error:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class SimpleImage could not be converted to string.

The Error-Line is where I bind the $image. How can I convert this Object to a string? Tried casting (string)($image_rez) but with no success.

Comment: Are you wanting to store the data in a BLOB column, or just store th file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$image_rez would be an image, which is best stored as a blob in your database. Change the type in bind_param to b, and remove (string).

Also, $image_rez is not the picture, but your entire SimpleImage object. You should file_get_contents($image_name.'.jpg') instead of $image_rez in the bind.

**Note**: A database is not the correct place to store an image. You should be storing it on the filesystem, with a path to the image stored in the database.

Comment: No, an image is best stored as an image in the filesystem, with a reference to the file path in the database.

Comment: Agreed, but if @JPM want's it in the DB for whichever reason, it should be stored as a BLOB and not a string.

Comment: Obviously, but he shouldn't do it in the first place, a database is the wrong tool to use to keep images. That should be noted in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Its working now. Can I user relative paths to store the images on the server? Cause Im using an admin-script in www.xxx.de/admin but I need to store the images in www.xxx.de/img/. Tried '../img' but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Best bet is to use absolute path, this will remove headaches in the future.